# Why are upserts so slow for MongoDB Java API?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

Using Mongo Java Driver 2.13 and Mongo 3.0.

I am trying to move from Spring Data save() to MongoDB API's Bulk Writing since I am saving/updating about 100K objects. I am trying to write the Service/Repository layer code where I can pass in a Collection of my specific Objects and be able to either create new records or update existing records, or in other words upsert. When I do an insert the performance is very acceptable.

If I update the code to do upserts the performance is just way too slow. Am I doing something wrong in the following code sample (note it is scaled down to just the necessary logic, i.e. no error handling):

```
public void save(Collection<MyDomainObject> objects) {
    BulkWriteOperation bulkWriter = dbCollection.initializeUnorderedBulkOperation();
    for(MyDomainObject mdo : objects) {
        DBObject dbObject = convert(mdo);
        bulkWriter.find(new BasicDBObject("id",mdo.getId()))
           .upsert().updateOne(new BasicDBObject("$set",dbObject));
    }
    bulkWriter.execute(writeConcern);
}
```

Note that I also tried replaceOne() instead of updateOne() with the same results.

I also noticed in the Mongo log that "nscannedObjects" keeps increasing while "nMatched", "nModified" and "upsert" are never larger than 1. Does this mean that it is table scanning for each record?

Am I using upsert the correct way? Any other suggestions?

Comment: Yes to you question about the full collection scan. If you use "explain" functionality you can see if an index was hit and the name of it. Have you checked for an index that correlates to the find and update? It should be in the "indexFilterSet" field.

Comment: You say "so slow with java", what are you comparing against? Or is it just "slow" for you in general? Why do you need to replace the whole document? If everything changes all the time that is not efficient.. Are the documents "growing"? MongoDB needs to allocate another space on disk if they are. What indexes are in place? You are only matching on the `_id` but writing other indexes takes time. Lots of possibilites here, and very little information.

Comment: Why do we need to replace the whole document? If we didn't than we probably wouldn't need Mongo. Mongo is supposed to be document based, right? The logic is to complex to keep track of which fields have or have not been updated.

Comment: @wxkevin You need to learn about [Update Operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/) which is one of the features that really distinquishes MongoDB from a basic key/value or document store. It's about changing only what you need to change. You would not update the whole row of a table in a relational database or multiple joined tables just because one column was changed, or a related row added. The same is true here as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to ry_donahue I figured out the issue.

It was not using the correct ID field, which is the index. In the conversion of the domain object to a DBObject there ended up being an "id" and an "_id" field.

I also changed updateOne() to replaceOne(). So now the code looks like this:

```
 public void save(Collection<MyDomainObject> objects) {
     BulkWriteOperation bulkWriter = dbCollection.initializeUnorderedBulkOperation();
    for(MyDomainObject mdo : objects) {
        DBObject dbObject = convert(mdo);
        bulkWriter.find(new BasicDBObject("_id",new ObjectId(mdo.getId()))).upsert().replaceOne(dbObject);
     }
     bulkWriter.execute(writeConcern);
 }
```

This now gives very good performance.